# Problems opening programs on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

Since completing a couple of Windows updates recently I have had no end of issues. Firstly, I cannot open many programs. I do not get an error message it just does nothing. The list of these includes control panel and task manager as well as things like Solitaire. I also cannot open command prompt as administrator which means I cannot perform a SFC scan. Additionally, I get many Windows notifications telling me I do not have any anti-virus protection even though I have Bitdefender installed and it seems to be working fine.

I also have issues creating new folders in File Explorer as it will usually lead to it not responding for ages. I am also unable to right click on anything in File Explore. Doing so closes file explorer completely.

I have tried opening services.msc to ensure Windows update service is running but when I try that I get an error saying 'Extended Attributes are Inconsistent'.

I seem to have also lost the ability to search from the start menu. Normally I would click on the start button and type the name of a program to search for it. Now when I type, nothing happens - no search box comes up or anything.

I am really hoping to avoid having to reinstall Windows so would be grateful if anyone knows of a way to fix these issues.

Comment: "he list of these includes control panel and task manager as well as things like Solitaire." - Solitaire is a UWP which means UAC must be enabled. "I also cannot open command prompt as administrator which means I cannot perform a SFC scan." - Why can't you open a command prompt as an Administrator?  If you cannot figure out how to run DISM and SFC then your only recourse is to either Reset your installation or reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: When I try to open command prompt as administrator it does nothing, just like the other programs I cannot open.